# To replace one or more comma separated values inside an object with some other value

Tags: javascript

I am having an Object, inside which I am having one key that has array of objects with following structure.

```
{"userId":"ab123","tenantMapList":[{"tenantId":"Essentials","igniteRoleIds":"Quality Analyst,Test Lead"},{"tenantId":"Essentials","igniteRoleIds":"Quality Analyst,Test Lead"},{"tenantId":"Essentials","igniteRoleIds":"Quality Analyst,Test Lead"}]}
```

Here, inside `igniteRoleIds` key, I want to replace comma separated strings with comma separated numbers. Like `Quality Analyst` as `1`, `Test Lead` as `2` etc.

I have tried following solution, but it didn't work for me.

```
 Object.keys(payload).map((item) => {
            console.log("item", item);
            if(item === "tenantMapList") {
              tenantMapList.map(function(item2) {
              if(item2.igniteRoleIds === "Quality Analyst")
              item2.igniteRoleIds = 1;
              if(item2.igniteRoleIds === "Test Lead")
              item2.igniteRoleIds = 2;
            })
          }
          })
```

where payload is the object I have pasted above.

Let me clarify that my initial json is same as I pasted above, but after modifying igniteRoleIds key, the output should look like the below one.

Expected output should be like this:

```
{
  "userId": "ab123",
  "tenantMapList": [
    {
      "tenantId": "Essentials",
      "igniteRoleIds":[
        1,2
      ]
    },
    {
      "tenantId": "Essentials",
     "igniteRoleIds":[
    1,2
    ]
    },
    {
      "tenantId": "Essentials",
      "igniteRoleIds":[
      1,2
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: what is the required output (sorry, your code isn't helping the description) ... and `tenantMapList.map(.....)` does nothing ... well, it returns an array of `undefined` which is immediately discarded - so, that code may as well not be there

Comment: your missing some code where did you take the variable "tenantMapList" from ?

Comment: If you're not interested in the return value of `.map()` then you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: Why `Object.keys()` and `.map()` at all? `payload.tenantMapList.forEach(...)`

Comment: Bunch of issues here, fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/v1w62jb8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a mapping of role names to role ids, and iterate each item replacing them:

```js
const input = {
  "userId": "ab123",
  "tenantMapList": [{ // was it intentional that this was an array in an array?
    "tenantId": "Essentials",
    "igniteRoleIds": "Quality Analyst,Test Lead"
  }, {
    "tenantId": "Essentials",
    "igniteRoleIds": "Quality Analyst,Test Lead"
  }, {
    "tenantId": "Essentials",
    "igniteRoleIds": "Quality Analyst,Test Lead"
  }]
}

const ROLES = {
  "Quality Analyst": 1,
  "Test Lead": 2
}

input.tenantMapList.forEach(item => {
  item.igniteRoleIds = (
    item.igniteRoleIds
      .split(',') // split on commas
      .map(s => ROLES[s] || s) // look up the corresponding number
    );
})

console.log(input);
```

Comment: _"i want to replace comma separated strings with comma separated numbers"_ - Without the expected output it's not clear but with the given input and the quoted text I think you might need a `.toString()`/`.join(",")` after the `.map()` call

Comment: Thanks Ray.
tenantMapList was not an array inside an array, I did it by mistake. Thanks you noticed it.
One more issue, inside igniteRoleIds key, value should not be in double code like "1,2". It should be just 1,2.

Comment: @Aditi `igniteRoleIds` has to be an actual array? Then remove the `.join(',')` call (**and add the expected output to your question!**)

Comment: @rayhatfield, i have pasted the exact output that i want in the question above. Please have a look.

Comment: @Aditi As already mentioned. Remove the `.join()` call

Comment: @Aditi I've removed the last `join` from my answer so you'll get an array `[1, 2]` instead of a string `"1,2"`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your igniteRoleIds is key whose value is a string. So, you can't directly compare it. Use split(',') to split string in an array of values. Another issue is you are not assigning your map value in a variable.
Here is the working example

```
var data = {
    "userId": "ab123",
    "tenantMapList": [
        [{
            "tenantId": "Essentials",
            "igniteRoleIds": "Quality Analyst,Test Lead"
        }, {
            "tenantId": "Essentials",
            "igniteRoleIds": "Quality Analyst,Test Lead"
        }, {
            "tenantId": "Essentials",
            "igniteRoleIds": "Quality Analyst,Test Lead"
        }]
    ]
}
data.tenantMapList.forEach(item => {
    const igniteRole = item
    igniteRole.map(igniteRole => {
        const role = igniteRole
        const changeData = igniteRole.igniteRoleIds.split(',').map(value => {
            if (value === 'Quality Analyst')
                return 1
            if (value === 'Test Lead')
                return 2
        })
        role.igniteRoleIds = changeData.toString()
        return igniteRole
    })
})
```

Result:

```
{
    "userId": "ab123",
    "tenantMapList": [
        [{
            "tenantId": "Essentials",
            "igniteRoleIds": "1,2"
        }, {
            "tenantId": "Essentials",
            "igniteRoleIds": "1,2"
        }, {
            "tenantId": "Essentials",
            "igniteRoleIds": "1,2"
        }]
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: Added answer as well sir :)